# Не работает Инсерт в БД?

Tags: php, mysql

вот такой простой код! и он не работает..

```
<?php
session_start(); //запускаем сессию. Обязательно в начале страницы
include ("bd.php"); // соединяемся с базой, укажите свой путь, если у вас уже есть соединение

$name = "Uje";

$result3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO coalition (name) VELUES ('$name')");//заносим в базу сообщение

if ($result3 == TRUE) {echo "TRU"; } else { echo "noo";}

echo $name;

?>
```

тип поля в БД "name" varchar(225)

на первый взгляд все верно но скрипт выдает "noo" как индикацию отсутствия результата не могу разобраться что не так( имя таблицы прописанно верно соединение с БД есть..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все было просто, у меня в таблице не стояли значения по умолчанию - а оказывается нельзя создавать ноую строку в БД когда значения остаются пустыми" а я в запросе некоторые значения не указывал)

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка у вас в слове **VALUES**:

```
$result3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `coalition` (`name`) VALUES ('$name')");
```

Comment: Все равно не работает(((

Comment: Попробуй переменную изолировать {$name} таким образом